# executing a .sh file from python indicating an absolute path

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

im kinda new to the python world and im having some issues running a bash file that will be automatically from my python script (using linux) .

i set my python script to create both  a text file .geo and a Bash file .sh in a directory somewhere in my Desktop like this :

```
    basedirectory="/home/pst2/Desktop/";
    *//Writing the .geo file* 
    file = open(basedirectory+nomdossier+"/"+nomfichier+".geo", 'w');
    file.write
        ..blabla
        ..blabla
    file.close();
    //Writing the .sh file 
    file = open(basedirectory+nomdossier+"/"+nomfichier+".sh", 'w');
    file.write
        ..blabla
        ..blabla
    file.close();
```

Now at this point my script works perfectly with all the variables set up and working fine and both those files that i created find themselves in this directory (for exemple after running the python script and entering the variables)

```
     /home/pst2/Desktop/test/ 
     (and in here you will find the new test.geo and test.sh that were created via the python script)
```

basically the test.sh when executed "manually" with  Bash test.sh ( whenever i am in its directory on ubuntu) will create another file called test.msh in the same directory
and  i cant seem to find the right coding , using  the subprocess modules to execute the newly created test.sh file automatically from the script .
is there a way to do so , like with indicating the absolute path to the .sh file 
(in our case  basedirectory+nomdossier+"/"+nomfichier+".sh ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are writing into the .sh file.

But to start with:

1. Have you started your .sh-file with the hashbang? #!/bin/sh
2. Have you modded your file as executable? chmod +x

After you have done this, you should be able to use subprocess module and do something like the example from the manual for subprocess:
subprocess.call([path_to_script+'/script.sh'])

I might have to update this answer if & when new information comes to my attention

Comment: yes my .sh is executable and the only issue here is that i dont know how to execute the bash file other that doing
                                 Bash test.sh 

and since i want to do it automatically from my python script and on top of that  , when writing ( bash test.sh) in the terminal it only works when i was on the same directory as my .sh .... i cant find a way to execute the newly created .sh file and the newly created directory file ;(

Comment: It might be because of the shell. Have yo provided a path for the system, so it knows where to find it. You able to either provide it in the proper environment variable or as full/relative path. Ex: /sbin/ls but as sbin is found in environment variable you are also able to write just ls

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the os module.

I believe

```
os.system("command_line_with_args")
```

could be what your looking for

Comment: my issue is that i dont know how to write a proper line code that takes into account the new path of the .sh file that i want to execute.
and since im new to the world of scripting it is kinda hard to apprehend the true difficulties of my issue ;(

Comment: @TAAMALLAHYoussef After reading [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-execute-sh-shell-script/) I think the command you are looking for is 'code' bash script-name-here.sh 'code'

Answer (score 0):

Roughly equivalent to "manually" executing `bash test.sh` with the current directory being the one where `test.sh` has been written by your posted code is:

```
    from subprocess import call
    call(['bash', 'test.sh'], cwd=basedirectory+nomdossier)
```